# gap test for random numbers

Tags: random

I'm in process of learning 'gap test' for random numbers in discrete event system simulation. I happened to have the fourth edition of this book by Jerry Banks. Unfortunately , this edition doesn't have any info about this test. I'm trying to learn more of it from the net but details are very scarce. So, can anyone please explain me this test in detail.

Comment: Do you have access to the book by *Knuth - The Art of Computer Programming. Vol. 2: Seminumerical Algorithms* that is referenced here [*TestU01*](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/myftp/papers/testu01.pdf)? Regards

Comment: im sry .. I dont have access to this book.

Comment: Is the description in the TestU01 paper sufficient?

Comment: no... its very scarce... I need an example to understand better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try section [*5.3 Gap Test*](http://www.rw.ethz.ch/alumni/thesis/Ruetti_Mario_Diplomarbeit.pdf), which contains a worked example, and also [*Section 3.*](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/students/reu/pRNGs.pdf) for an alternate description.

I would still recommend getting your hands on Knuth - The Art of Computer Programming. Vol. 2: Seminumerical Algorithms.

Also, I would recommend looking into [*DIEHARDERs*](http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php) and [*TestU01s*](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/myftp/papers/testu01.pdf) implementations of these tests since both provide actual working code (and there are certainly other variants out there, but those two are heavily used).

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your help... I'll get my hands on the book by Knuth. The example given in the first link isn't so clear. After going through explanation from the UMinessota's notes it's a bit clearer. Thanks for the links to the working codes.

Comment: Nice answer, nice feedback, ++ $\land \checkmark$